# ExcelService Error while saving a workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint-2010, soapexception

I have a problem with using ExcelService in Sharepoint 2010.

Case:
I have a template Excel File, and i copied it to some folder and then tried to fill cells in new document:

This code creates a file:

```
SPList documents = Web4Documents.GetListEx("Lists/RequestDocuments");
SPFolder folder =            documents.RootFolder.SubFolders.Add(_formContext.Request.Number).SubFolders.Add("Docs");
string path = folder.ServerRelativeUrl.AddUrl("Document.xlsx");
SPFile document = Web4Documents.Files.Add(path, stream, null, true);
```

After that I open this file using Excel Service:

```
using (Workbook workbook = client.OpenWorkbook(_context._SiteOriginal.MakeFullUrl(DocumentPath)))
        {
            //workbook.SetCell("A1", "TEST");
            workbook.SetCellByCoords("List1", 1, 1, "test");
            workbook.Save();
        }
```

This is a implementation of workbook`s Save method:

```
public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            _service.SaveWorkbook(_session);
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
            throw new ASUPTPException("SOAP exception message: {0}, ERROR_CODE:", ex.Message, ex.SubCode.Code.Name);
        }
    }
```

And I get SoapException: "An error occurred while attempting to save your workbook.  As a result, the workbook was not saved". Error code: FileSaveGeneric

Template file is empty.

Can anybody tell me why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by turning off all but one Excel Service in the cluster..

It is strange..but it works now